# python passlib verify doesn't match

Tags: python, mongodb, passlib

I am working with Flask and MongoDB, trying to implement username / password verification with passlib.

The class from models.py :

```
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

class Users(object):
    def __init__(self, username='', password='', collection=db.users, articles=''):
    self.collection = collection
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.articles = []

def addUser(self):
    self.collection.insert({'username': self.username, 'password': sha256_crypt.encrypt('self.password'), 'articles': self.articles})
```

From the python shell, I create the user alice with the password 'secret' :

```
>>> import models
>>> alice = models.Users()
>>> alice.username = 'alice'
>>> alice.password = 'secret'
>>> alice.addUser()
```

From the mongo shell, I check that the document has been well created with a hash instead of the clear password :

```
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f15d9f815a0b6c1533427f"), "username" : "alice", "articles" : [ ], "password" : "$5$rounds=535000$Oq1hy1INzO59nu0q$FzMz1DtBWDwM.sw0AhrlVA8esgE30n8rr/NjOltB8.7" }
```

From now on, we should be able to verify the password from the python shell using the hash stored in the document, isn't it ?

```
>>> sha256_crypt.verify('secret','$5$rounds=535000$Oq1hy1INzO59nu0q$FzMz1DtBWDwM.sw0AhrlVA8esgE30n8rr/NjOltB8.7')
False
```

But it doesn't, someone can explain to me why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because you're encrypting not `self.password` but `'self.password'`

So you need to change your `addUser` method to the following:

```
def addUser(self):
    self.collection.insert({'username': self.username, 'password': sha256_crypt.encrypt(self.password), 'articles': self.articles})
```

Comment: God, so obvious XDXD - Thank you !